# How can I run my rake tests twice on purpose?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I need to run my `rake` tests twice in order to test the caching system of my Ruby gem. Before both the tests run, I need to clear my app's cache with

```
require 'lib/gem_name'
Gem.cache.clear
```

Then I just need to run the `test` task twice. I've tried putting the above code at the top of my `Rakefile` and listing the test files two times in my rake task, but I receive `cannot require such file` errors due to the gem `lib` paths not being loaded properly.

I need an efficient way to run the test twice, rather than running the cache-emptying code in IRB and then running `rake test` two times on the command line.

My `Rakefile` looks like this:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.test_files = FileList['tests/test_*.rb']
  t.loader = :testrb
end

desc 'Run gem tests'
task default: :test
```

Comment: would this shell script suffice? `ruby -e " require 'lib/gem_name'; Gem.cache.clear"; rake test; rake test;`

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but since I use Travis CI to test my build externally I'd rather just be able to run `rake test` once and not have to worry about running scripts.

Comment: Otherwise that's the exact functionality I was looking for, I would just like it in Ruby form.

Comment: could you make another rake task, say `do_test`, that runs that shell script using system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @maxple's comments and @OneNeptune's answer I found a way to achieve what I want. In my modified `Rakefile` below I set up a new task to clear the cache, and then a new `test` task which empties the cache and runs the tests twice.

```
require 'rake/testtask'

desc 'Clear gem cache'
task :clear_cache do
  lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
  require 'gem_name'
  Gem.cache.clear
end

desc 'Perform tests exactly once'
Rake::TestTask.new(:run_tests) do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.test_files = FileList['tests/test_*.rb']
  t.loader = :testrb
end

desc 'Performs test setup and runs tests twice'
task :test do
  Rake::Task['clear_cache'].execute
  Rake::Task['run_tests'].execute
  Rake::Task['run_tests'].execute
end

task default: :test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either reenable the task like:

```
task :test do |task|
    task.execute 1
    task.execute 2
    task.execute 3
end
```

which is superior to reenable since reenable would look like this:

```
task :test do |task|
    task.invoke 1
    task.reenable
    task.invoke 2
    task.reenable
    task.invoke 3
end
```

You can read more about execute vs invoke here: https://blog.simplificator.com/2014/12/30/rake-execute-vs-invoke/